# I want to create a method to pass a value from text field to check box in two different java windows

Tags: java, methods, checkbox, timer, textfield

I have created a program that displays the current time and has the option to set an alarm by opening a second window with a button. Once you enter the time for the alarm in the second window you activate the alarm in the first window with a check box. I've created both windows but I am unsure as to how to pass the variables for the alarm in the second window to the check box in the first window.

Code for the first window:

```
enter code here
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise18_21 extends JFrame {

private JTextField jtfHour, jtfMinute, jtfSeconds, jtfAlarm;
private JLabel hour, minute, seconds;
private JCheckBox jchkAlarm;
private JButton jbtAlarm;
private SetAlarm setAlarm = new SetAlarm();
private JFrame SetAlarmFrame = new JFrame();
private javax.swing.Timer  t;
private int alarmHour;
    //private int num1, num2, num3;


public Exercise18_21() 
{
setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,2,2));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

hour = new JLabel("Hour");
add(hour, c);

minute = new JLabel("Minutes");
add(minute, c);

seconds = new JLabel("Seconds");
add(seconds, c);

jtfHour = new JTextField(10);
add(jtfHour, c);

jtfMinute= new JTextField(5);
add(jtfMinute, c);

jtfSeconds = new JTextField(5);
add(jtfSeconds, c);

jchkAlarm = new JCheckBox("Alarm");
add(jchkAlarm, c);

jbtAlarm = new JButton("Set Alarm");
add(jbtAlarm, c);

javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ClockListener());
    t.start();

jbtAlarm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
SetAlarmFrame.setVisible(true);
}
});

jchkAlarm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        jtfHour.setText("" + h);
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        jtfMinute.setText("" + m);
        int S = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        jtfSeconds.setText("" + S);
        //System.out.print(h);
        //System.out.print(m);
        //System.out.print(S);


}
});



SetAlarmFrame.add(setAlarm);
SetAlarmFrame.pack();
SetAlarmFrame.setTitle("Set Alarm");


}//end of constructor
private int getHour() {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int alarmHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);



return alarmHour; // Return hour
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////// inner class ClockListener
class ClockListener implements ActionListener 
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        jtfHour.setText("" + h);
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        jtfMinute.setText("" + m);
        int S = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        jtfSeconds.setText("" + S);

    }
}

public static void main(String [] arg) {
Exercise18_21 gui = new Exercise18_21();
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.setVisible(true);
gui.setSize(200, 100);
gui.setTitle("Exercise18_21");
}//end of main
}//end of exercise18_21 class
```

Code for the second window to setAlarm:

```
enter code here
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class SetAlarm extends JPanel {

private JTextField jtfHour2, jtfMinute, jtfSeconds;
private JLabel hour, minute, seconds;
private JButton jbtOK, jbtCancel;
private int num1, num2, num3;

public SetAlarm() 
{
setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,2,2));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

hour = new JLabel("Hour");
add(hour, c);

jtfHour2 = new JTextField(10);
add(jtfHour2, c);

minute = new JLabel("Minutes");
add(minute, c);

jtfMinute= new JTextField(5);
add(jtfMinute, c);

seconds = new JLabel("Seconds");
add(seconds, c);

jtfSeconds = new JTextField(5);
add(jtfSeconds, c);

jbtOK = new JButton("OK");
add(jbtOK, c);

jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

add(jbtCancel, c);

jbtCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.exit(0);
}
});


jbtOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    int alarmHour  = getHour();

        //int num1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfHour2.getText().trim());
        //int num2 = Integer.parseInt(jtfMinute.getText().trim());
        //int num3 = Integer.parseInt(jtfSeconds.getText().trim());

        System.out.print(alarmHour);
        System.out.print(num2);
        System.out.print(num3);
}
});

}//end of constructor

public void showHour(int alarmHour)
{
this.alarmHour = alarmHour;

} 

public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
{
return new Dimension(200, 200);

}//end of Dimension getPreferredSize
}//end of setAlarm class
```

**New code for second window:**

```
    public class SetAlarm extends JDialog {

private JTextField jtfHour2, jtfMinute, jtfSeconds;
private JLabel hour, minute, seconds;
private JButton jbtOK, jbtCancel;
protected int num1, num2, num3;



public SetAlarm() 
{
setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,2,2));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

hour = new JLabel("Hour");
add(hour, c);

jtfHour2 = new JTextField(10);
add(jtfHour2, c);

minute = new JLabel("Minutes");
add(minute, c);

jtfMinute= new JTextField(5);
add(jtfMinute, c);

seconds = new JLabel("Seconds");
add(seconds, c);

jtfSeconds = new JTextField(5);
add(jtfSeconds, c);

jbtOK = new JButton("OK");
add(jbtOK, c);

jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

add(jbtCancel, c);

jbtCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);
}
});


jbtOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{


        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfHour2.getText().trim());
        //int num2 = Integer.parseInt(jtfMinute.getText().trim());
        //int num3 = Integer.parseInt(jtfSeconds.getText().trim());

        //System.out.print(alarmHour);
        //System.out.print(num2);
        //System.out.print(num3);
        setVisible(false);
}
});

}//end of constructor

public int getHour()
{ 
return num1;

} 

public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
{
return new Dimension(200, 200);

}//end of Dimension getPreferredSize
}//end of setAlarm class
```

**New code for first window**

```
public class Exercise18_21 extends JFrame {

private JTextField jtfHour, jtfMinute, jtfSeconds, jtfAlarm;
private JLabel hour, minute, seconds;
private JCheckBox jchkAlarm;
private SetAlarm setAlarm1= new SetAlarm();;
private JButton jbtAlarm;

private int h1, m1, s1;
//private JFrame SetAlarmFrame = new JFrame();
private javax.swing.Timer  t;

    //private int num1, num2, num3;


public Exercise18_21() 
{
setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,2,2));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

hour = new JLabel("Hour");
add(hour, c);

minute = new JLabel("Minutes");
add(minute, c);

seconds = new JLabel("Seconds");
add(seconds, c);

jtfHour = new JTextField(10);
add(jtfHour, c);

jtfMinute= new JTextField(5);
add(jtfMinute, c);

jtfSeconds = new JTextField(5);
add(jtfSeconds, c);

jchkAlarm = new JCheckBox("Alarm");
add(jchkAlarm, c);

jbtAlarm = new JButton("Set Alarm");
add(jbtAlarm, c);

javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ClockListener());
    t.start();

jbtAlarm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
setAlarm1.setVisible(true);
}
    });

jchkAlarm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{




        setAlarm1.setModal(true) ;
        setAlarm1.getHour();
        int h1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfHour.getText().trim());
        System.out.print(setAlarm1.num1);


}
});








//SetAlarmFrame.add(setAlarm);
//SetAlarmFrame.pack();
//SetAlarmFrame.setTitle("Set Alarm");


}//end of constructor


/////////////////////////////////////////////// inner class ClockListener
class ClockListener implements ActionListener 
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        jtfHour.setText("" + h);
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        jtfMinute.setText("" + m);
        int S = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        jtfSeconds.setText("" + S);

    }
}

public static void main(String [] arg) {
Exercise18_21 gui = new Exercise18_21();
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.setVisible(true);
gui.setSize(200, 100);
gui.setTitle("Exercise18_21");
}//end of main
}//end of exercise18_21 class
```

Answer (score 0):

just extend your second frame from JDialog.
add action listeners to your Ok and cancel buttons in dialog and call setVisible(false) in both of them,
create a method in your dialog that returns desired alarm time (like getAlarmTime())
call your secend frame (the dialog) like this :

```
    SampleDialog dialog = new SampleDialog() ;
dialog.setModal(true) ;
dialog.setVisible(true) ;
    Date alarmTime = dialog.getAlarmTime() ;
```

then do what ever you want with alarmTime object.

Comment: I almost got it but my variable num1 is always zero.            setAlarm1.getHour();
System.out.print(setAlarm1.num1);

Comment: Are you sure your dialog extends JDialog and you set dialog.setModal(true) ? And make sure you have a button in that dialog , you have an action listener on that button and when your button is pressed, first do something like this : num1 = textField.getText(); and then this.setVisible(false);
send me your dialog code and the part that you called this dialog.

Comment: here is your problem : in second window code where you wrote jbtOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfHour2.getText().trim());
note that you created new varialbe named num1, this is not the num1 that you've defined in your class as a field, get rid of the "int" and you're done here.
in your actinoPerformed code in first window, you must do like this:
setAlarm1.setModal(true) ;
setAlarm1.setVisible(true) ;
 System.out.print(setAlarm1.num1);